# MongoDB aggregate & lookup between 3 collections

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to create a simple DB of customers/products/orders.
[This is the customer collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83qQF.png)

[This is the order collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhsIU.png)

[This is the product collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoRYW.png)

I prefered using ref key and not embedded document just to exercise.
What I am trying to so is to group by customer name and then sum for each customer his total orders= Sum (Product_price x Quantity).

This is the query I tried but it doesn't work :/

```
db.customers.aggregate([
  {$lookup:{from:"orders", localField:"ordered",foreignField:"_id", as:"Bought"}},
  {$lookup:{from:"products", localField:"Bought.Includes.product",foreignField:"_id", as:"User_products"}},
  {$group:{_id:{name:"$name"},total: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] }}},
  {$project: {name:1, total:1}  }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: You posted the same image for order & product

Comment: No problem, welcome to Stack Overflow. Another tip: Please avoid posting images of data and post the data as text in the question content instead. You can make use of the editor formatting functions to make it more readable. Please consult the guide here about how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, just a few issues. Explanation in the code's comment

```js
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "orders",
      localField: "ordered",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "Bought"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$Bought' //  You have to use $unwind on an array if you want to use a field in the subdocument array to further usage with `$lookup` 
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$Bought.Includes' // Also $unwind here
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      localField: "Bought.Includes.product",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "User_products"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$User_products' // also $unwind here
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name" , // [optional] only one field to use as key, no need to wrap in an object
      total: {
        $sum: { // don't forget to $sum here
          $multiply: [
            "$User_products.Price", // access the value with the full object path
            "$Bought.Includes.quantity" // access the value with the full object
          ]
        } 
      }
    }
  },
]
```

More about [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Tip: make sure you have consistent usage with uppercase/lowercase, I noticed you use `product` vs `Price` vs `Quantity` it will be more prone to misspellings

Comment: Yes, I always forget uper/lower hehe . I get this error now for some reason https://imgur.com/a/FW8e5gN

Comment: Forgot to $unwind another stage, I have modified the answer to include the fix

Comment: Thanks buddy, works! I have a question: i come from SQL and new to mongoDB - is the way I created the collection is right? using the ref key like I did is correct or there's better ways? because "joining" like you just did can be hell and i wonder if there's better way to create the collection to better query

Comment: In the NoSQL world there are mostly multiple ways to design the schema. Most often it is going to depend on the access pattern of your data, i.e. how you query it. You can get started with the following guides: 1. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/ 2. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1